# Write to Excel very large numeric value

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am trying to write to Excel using Excel Interop. One of my column will have a very numeric value (44 digits).

After checking similar posts in the internet, I tried setting the NumberFormat.
`worksheet.Cells[i, j].NumberFormat = "@";` and `worksheet.Cells[i, j].NumberFormat = "#";`

But it still shows the values in format- ######... so on.. I tried expanding the columns too but that did not work. However, this worked for some of my other column where I have numeric values in 14 digits.

Any help? Please let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: A workaround might be to output the value as text, rather than a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 15 digit limit in Excel unfortunately

for cells use cells["A:A"].numberFormat = "@";

for columns use cells[0, 2].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";

Comment: if you are going to use the number for calculations then i think its impossible to do that with over 15 digits.. But, if you wish to only write it down as information then just format the cell as TEXT. Formatting as text is done on the HOME page in the Number group, on the arrow, right next to the Number Format Box.

Comment: Yes I didit manually. But I need to do it through code. I just want to display and no calculations needed as of now.

Comment: for cells use cells["A:A"].numberFormat = "@";

for columns use cells[0, 2].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";

Comment: Yes it worked. Please update the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: updated my original answer. Glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 0):

If showing the data in text is ok , then set the cell format to **TEXT**.

Comment: So how do I do that?